# How to add and vary Gaussian noise to input data

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, normal-distribution, noise

I have a time-series data and I would like to add an additive Gaussian Noise to the input of the data. What I am trying to do is that I want to test my ML predictive model against different level of noises.

I found that there are two common ways to add noises.

**1. Vary the standard deviation**.

For example, I can change the values of standard deviation such as [0.1,0.2,0.3] to represent different level of noises.

The Python code would be:

```
# x is my training data
# mu is the mean
# std is the standard deviation
mu=0.0
std = 0.1
def gaussian_noise(x,mu,std):
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, std, size = x.shape)
    x_noisy = x + noise
    return x_noisy
```

**2. change the percentage of Gaussian noise added to data**.

For example, I add 5% of gaussian noise to my data then change it to 10% etc. In this case, the Python code would look like:

```
mu=0.0
std = 0.05 * np.std(x) # for %5 Gaussian noise
def gaussian_noise(x,mu,std):
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, std, size = x.shape)
    x_noisy = x + noise
    return x_noisy
```

**I have two questions:**

1. On which basis one can vary the standard deviation?
2. What is the more appropriate way to add and vary the noise to the
   data?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `np.around`? The result of rounding a Gaussian RV is a RV that is no longer Gaussian. // Either function could be correct, depending on the purpose and goals of adding noise.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up questions. In terms of the purpose, I am trying to come up with a predictive model that is robust to noise. Therefore, I want to test it with different level of noises. In terms of ```np.around```, yes you are right I should have emitted this one.

Comment: Is additive, iid gaussian noise a realistic kind of noise to expect in your specific problem?

Comment: Actually, I expect to have both gaussian and non-gaussain noises in my problem.

Comment: may I point out that camel case is not cool in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your question is how to vary the std. dev. of the noise level, whether absolute units (0.1,0.2,0.3), percentage of signal or other.

I would suggest using [signal to noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) as a parameter to vary, since it's use has a solid background (in Kalman filtering for instance).

So in Python I would do something like:

```
sp = np.mean( x**2 ) # Signal Power

for snr in array_of_snr_values: 
      std_n = ( sp / snr )**0.5 # Noise std. deviation
      test_perdictive_model( std_n )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean that I fixed the std. and use different values of SNR (dB)? I just rewrote my question to make it more clear.

Comment: 1. In both cases that you illustrate above you're adding noise from a random variable ( noise = np.random.normal(mu, std, size = x.shape) ), the only thing you vary is how yo select the value of std.

Comment: 2. If you use different values of SNR you need to vary the std deviation of the added noise accordingly, since SNR depends from the std deviation of the added noise. So I am suggesting you vary SNR, and compute the std dev of noise from the value or SNR

Comment: Just a quick question, does high values of dB mean the signal is clean. As I found it a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, a high SNR means that there is a lot of signal and very few noise present