# the signal (numerically generated) is polluted by white noise with amplitude of 10% -- what does that mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, noise

In a paper, I read that "the values are polluted by white noise of amplitude up to 10%".
Say, the referred values are stored in a vector `x`, what is meant by amplitude in this regard?

Comment: 10% of the average or max magnitude of the original data vector.

Comment: Ok. Here, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548619/how-to-add-and-vary-gaussian-noise-to-input-data , it was done differently. But I guess it depends on the definition, right?

Comment: "Polluted" sounds like a mis-translation of a word originally rendered as "contaminated."  A "contaminated" distribution is a technical term: it refers to one mixed with a small component assigning substantial probabilities to values considered extreme or unusual.  What the writer means by "amplitude," though, is ambiguous: it might be either (a) the amount of contamination or (b) the standard deviation of the white noise or even (c) the variance of the white noise.  How this might be implemented on a computer, or stored in a vector, is irrrelevant.